# Replace a while ( 1 == 1) loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I have been unable to find something related to this so far.  I've heard that surrounding the majority of your program in a while loop like this makes the program inefficient, is there any better way to get the same effect?

```
    while (1 == 1) {
        //User Input 
        System.out.println("Do you wish to roll? (Y/N)"); 
        if (kb.hasNext()) {
            userContinue = kb.next(); 
        }
        if (userContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //Calculations 
        score = 0; 
        while (userContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            rollResult = user.rollTwoDie(); 
            score = rollResult + score; 
            if (score > 21) {
                System.out.println("You loose for going over 21."); 
                System.out.println("Your final score was: " + score); 
                score = 0; 
                System.out.println("Play again? (Y/N)"); 
                if (kb.hasNext()) {
                    userContinue = kb.next(); 
                }
                if (userContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    System.exit(0); 
                }
            }
            else if (score <= 21) {
                System.out.println("Your score is: " + score); 
                System.out.println("Roll again? (Y/N)"); 
                if (kb.hasNext()) {
                    userContinue = kb.next(); 
                }
            }
        }
        if (userContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            while (computerScore <= score && computerScore < max) {
                computerResult = computer.rollTwoDie(); 
                computerScore = computerResult + computerScore; 
            }
            userContinue = computer.checkComputerScore(computerScore, score); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while(true)` or `for(;;)`. There's nothing inherently wrong with this.

Comment: `"I've heard that surrounding the majority of your program in a while loop like this makes the program inefficient..."` -- please show us a reference for this as I've never heard anything like this before. A while loop has nothing to do with efficiency.

Comment: `while(1 == 1)` is very odd. `while(true)` is much more normal. Other than that, if you need an infinite loop then that's what you need. You really shouldn't call `System.exit`, simply use `break`.

Comment: if you want it can be played infinite times, then nothing wrong is with while..

Comment: As to a reference for the inefficiency, just look at SME_Dev's answer below.

Comment: I think you should read my answer for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily inefficient. It will just run endlessly. If you want that then this isn't necessarily evil.

One thing you may consider is adding a stop boolean. That way you can ask the user if they want to quit, and set the variable to true/false.

```
boolean stop = false;
while(stop == false) {
    //...
}
```

Also, stylistically I like doing infinite while loops like this:

```
while(true) {
    //...
}
```

Instead of using "1==1"

Comment: Whenever I ask the player if he/she wants to quit, I just used System.exit(0), but if the loop isn't exceedingly dangerous than I'll keep using it since this is just going to be a relatively simple program for homework.

Comment: @DJOwen: how the heck does this make anything more "efficient"? Your question baffles my mind, and I not even sure that you know what you're asking.

Comment: `while(stop == false)` or `while(!stop)`?! Never use `==` for this.

Comment: It doesn't make it more efficient, however considering I haven't gotten a better answer, and it (most likely) won't make my computer go up in smoke, it's good enough for me.

Comment: @DJOwen: Kamil's answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

1. I'm not Java guy, but in many languages `1==1` is usually optimized to `true` anyway.

   So you can use `while(true)` or `while(1==1)` or even `while (2==2)`.

   It doesn't matter.
2. In your case it doesn't matter even more, because **your while loop is not forcing CPU to work a lot**. Your loop is waiting for user input for most of the time. **Don't worry about this in this case.**
3. While loops can be extremely inefficient in some cases. In these cases - it's better to use **Events instead of loops**.

Theoretical example of very incorrect inefficient while loop:

```
 while(true)
 {
      if(textBox1.Text == "yes") x = 1;
      if(textBox1.Text == "no") x = 2;

      if (x == 1) doSomething();
      if (x == 2) doSomethingElse();
 }
```

It is very inefficient, because you "ask" interface about data in textbox again and again, and there is no reason to do this. There is no pause, CPU and memory are forced to do same thing again and again without pause. In this case - Event should be used.

Events exist in many programming languages. There are many sites, videos and tutorials explaining Events.

Take a look at this video about Events in Java:

[Java Programming Tutorial - 52 - Event Handling on Youtube (by Bucky Roberts)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EE7E3bvfe8)

After watching this (and maybe few more Bucky or other tutorial videos) you should understand better why while loops are bad idea sometimes.